SQL using in operator with fetch first rows only
I have a table with millions of records and want to search for names.
Is it possible to say that only the first match of each record for name '12' and '23' should be outputted?
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE NAME IN ('12', '23')
Example:
TABLE_A



ID
Name




1
12


2
23


3
12


4
24


5
25



Expected results should be only ids:
1 or 3 and 2

Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output as text ?

This question is similar to: Equivalent of LIMIT for DB2. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This can be done using the window function ROW_NUMBER() as follows :
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id ) AS rn
  FROM TABLE_A a
  WHERE NAME IN ('12', '23')
) AS s
WHERE s.rn = 1;

Demo here

Doesn't FETCH FIRST, LIMIT 1, TOP, ROWNUM solve your use cases?
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE NAME IN ('12', '23') FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY should work.

consider adding more detail to your solution, how it is better from other solutions and any references, good luck :)

SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A a
WHERE NAME IN ('12', '23')
  AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY some_column_you_can_use_to_sort ) = 1;

You can determine which record is considered the "first" by specifying the order in which the records are sorted.
ROW_NUMBER() assigns a unique number to each row within a partition of a result set.
